Enriques' principle of deformation from Zariski's viewpoint
In his "Theory and applications of holomorphic functions on algebraic varieties over arbitrary ground fields" Oscar Zariski commented on page 3 on so called "Principle of Degeneration" coined by Enriques, which asserts loosely that if $V$ is an irreducible variety, which degenerates, in the limit, into a reducible variety $V_0$, then the latter must be connected.
Zariski wrote that this principle is "almost self-evident", since $V_0$ is continuous image of $V$, and images of connected spaces under continuous maps are clearly connected.
First critical comment: But wouldn't then applying this "logic" that $V_0$ comes as continuous image of irreducible $V$ even automatically force $V_0$ to be irreducible? But following Zariski it seems that Enriques allowed $V_0$ to be reducible. Isn't this self-contradicting?
Therefore I'm confused. Why, if Enriques believed in this principle, why $V_0$ is allowed to be reducible. Wouldn't believing in that $V_0$ continuous image of irreducible $V$ force it be also irreducible? I doubt that neither Enriques nor Zariski overlooked this seemingly obvious flaw, so I guess I misread/misunderstand this part. Could anybody clarify that point?
Zariski made also at the end of this page at footnote on "almost self-evident":
That of course to assert that $V_0$ is continuous image of $V$ "the continuous variation of $V$ should be accompanied by continuous deformation of $V$ to $V_0$.
This raises a couple of questions:
Firstly about prelimnaries, I guess that varieties $V$ and $V_0$ Enriques & contemporary geometers of Italian School worked in that context with families whose members like $V$ were always assumed to be projective (especially complete) over $\Bbb C$, right? Especially, completeness (...in modern terms properness) is important, as Zariski's connectedness Theorem fails if the family would be not proper.
Intuitive reason /example: Take a family of smooth quadric curves deforming to a "cross" (=transversal intersection of two lines); assume the intersection would be a point at infinity. Then in "affine picture" this would be disconnected; so properness/ completeness we need not to "lose" some points
Question 1:
What was for Enriques & contemporary geometers of Italian School a "deformation"? The same thing as in modern algebraic geometry? I doubt so, as Zariski remarked in footnote that he seemingly tacitly assumed existence of continuous surjective map $V \to V_0$.
Deformations in modern terms don't admit such maps, so the question what was actually for Enriques a deformation of $V$ to $V_0$.
Remark: The assumed existence of such $V \to V_0$ reminds me more on the arguments used in Ehresmann lemma where one locally constucts via flows induced by lifted vector fields maps between neighbored fibres.
Question 2: Assume Enriques indeed tacitly assumed that there exists such a continuous deformation $V \to V_0$.
But then, why he believed in his "Principle of Degeneration" that $V_0$ may be reducible? Wouldn't $V_0$ being closed image of irreducible $V$ consequently imply $V_0$ to be even irreducible.
But following Zariski's exposition $V_0$ was allowed to be reducible. Isn't this self-contradicting? Either one believes that there is continuous dominant $V \to V_0$, then $V_0$ must be also irreducible, or not, but then if Enriques did not believe in such a map how else Enriques thought/tacitly justified his "Principle of Deformation"?
Of course I'm aware that Enriques never used it formally, but I wonder which intuition he had behind this principle. That way I sketched it before seemingly would force to believe that $V_0$ much be irreducible, but he explicitly insisted that this shall not be the case. But I doubt that Enriques overlooked such banal point.
Therefore I'm wondering what actually Enriques meant by his degeneration principle and why this was about connectedness and not even irreducibility of $V_0$ assuming he took continuous $V \to V_0$ to exist for granted.
Does somebody know more about this issue?

Brigaglia et al. in The Italian School comment that "Enriques uses the so-called principio di spezzamento (splitting principle), which essentially says that when an irreducible, may be singular, curve, varying in a continuous family on a smooth surface, becomes reducible in, say, two irreducible components, then, roughly speaking, it acquires at least one more singularity which connects the two components." This might explain why connectedness of the limit does not translate for Enriques into its irreducibility.

@Conifold: But then this suggests that the part where Zariski wrote about "almost self-evident" heuristic justification for connectedness principle assuming that $V_0$ is continous image of $V$ ($V$ irreducible) is missing the issue, right? Indeed, such $2$- component curve in which the singular irreducible curve degenerates in this quoted example can never be "continuous image" of the latter from topological reasons, right? Do you maybe have an idea what Zariski else meant there by "continuous image"?

Why not? One can 'continuously deform' a circle into figure 8 by pressing two opposite points towards each other along the diameter until they meet at the center. Connectivity is a topological notion closely related to continuity, so it makes sense that it is preserved in 'continuous deformations' while an algebraic notion like irreducibility is not.

@Conifold: Thank you, I think I see the reason for my now. Firstly, indeed continuous image on an irreducible space is irreducible (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Irreducible_topological_space). Proof sketch, assume $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, wlog irreducible & $X$ irreducible. Assume image $Y= Y_1 \cup Y_2$ reducible. Then we consider preimages of $Y_i$... The discrepance with your plausible example seems to be that your deformation is continuous only with resp classical/analytic topology, but not with Zariski: The both o's of the 8 are closed with resp analytic & Zariski topology, but

(cont) their preimages under your deformation map inside the circle are closed only wrt classical/analytic topology. So it seems that Enriques thought there about continuity of the deformation map only in termsof classical topology, with resp to which your presented deformation map is indeed continuous.Thanks for pointing that out! It seems a bit paradoxical, Enriques considered (complex) algebraic varieties resp their famifies, but allowed there continuous maps in analytic topology between, which potentially could make preimage of an algebraic variety non algebraic as in your example :)

NB & summary: So the gist is really that connectedness of an algebraic set is for classical and Zariski topology equivalent, but for irreducibility that's highly wrong, and conseqently, continuous maps with classical topology can destroy given irreducibility in the image  with respect Zariski topology. That was my thinking error...

This sounds plausible. The idea of different topologies, especially algebraic ones, was not something classical geometers pondered, and Italian school was particularly lax on precision and rigor. Enriques' "continuous deformations" were just intuitive. Brigaglia et al. write on his use of the "splitting principle":"It would be too long, and perhaps a desperate task, to try to explain Enriques’ application of this principle... The point
is that, though the splitting principle is correct Enriques argument fails since nobody ensures us that the infinitesimal deformations... are not obstructed"

@Conifold: One nitpick: The last quoted sentence suggests that the reason for nowdays known failure of "Enriques argument" is that infinitesimal deformations may be subjected to that there are some "obstructions", although the "splitting principle" itself is correct. Could you sketch the idea or give a reference for what actually the mentioned obstructions "obstruct" (... guess: presumambly liftability of local extensions), and why if these obstructions would hypothetically not exsist, then even Enriques' "flawed argument" would work? (That's how I undrstood last part)

The paper goes into some detail, but I am not an expert to summarize it. Apparently, obstructed deformations contribute to the cokernel of restriction map from the zero sheaf cohomology of the surface to the curve.
